# Angularjs: <iframe> not loading CSS of source page inside partials

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, iframe, partials

I'm using <\iframe> in a partials. It can load the source page but the CSS is not loaded in the inner page. Here is my code:

**all_widget.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="./templates/widget_2.html" my-iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**directives.js**

```
app.directive('myIframe', function() {
  var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.find('iframe').bind('load', function(event) {
        event.target.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 400);
    });
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        src: '@src',
        height: '@height',
        width: '@width',
        scrolling: '@scrolling'
    },
    template: '<iframe class="frame" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="{{scrolling}}" src="{{src}}"></iframe>',
    link: linkFn
  };
});
```

Comment: You would have an iframe within an iframe here this might be causing some issues.  What is the html of widget_2.html I assume this is a well formed html document with a <html> and <head> tags?

Comment: Ok, now I have using this way: <my-iframe src="./templates/widget_2.html"></my-iframe> but still the css is missing in the source page. widget_2.html is just a partials only <div> tag contents are written..

Comment: An IFrame is a seperate html page so if the html is only a div the style would not be loaded it would have to be a proper html page.  Have you thought about just using ngInclude instead???

Comment: Thanks Jon for your concern. Actually CSS are not included inside partials, so it was not loading. Now I created a separate page with the <\iframe> and I'm loading the whole app inside it. it solves the problem.\